# Migration from setup.py to pyproject.toml: how to specify package name?

Tags: python, setup.py, pyproject.toml

I'm currently trying to move our internal projects away from `setup.py` to `pyproject.toml` ([PEP-518](https://peps.python.org/pep-0518)). I'd like to not use build backend specific configuration if possible, even though I do specify the backend in the `[build-system]` section by `require`'ing it.

The `pyproject.toml` files are more or less straight-forward translations of the `setup.py` files, with the metadata set according to [PEP-621](https://peps.python.org/pep-0621), including the `dependencies`. We are using `setuptools_scm` for the determination of the version, therefore the `version` field ends up in the `dynamic` section.

We used to set the `packages` parameter to `setup` in our `setup.py` files, but I couldn't find any corresponding field in `pyproject.toml`, so I simply omitted it.

When building the project using `python3 -m build .`, I end up with a package named `UNKNOWN`, even though I have the `name` field set in the `[project]` section. It seems that this breaks very early in the build:

```
$ python -m build .
* Creating virtualenv isolated environment...
* Installing packages in isolated environment... (setuptools, setuptools_scm[toml]>=6.2, wheel)
* Getting dependencies for sdist...
running egg_info
writing UNKNOWN.egg-info/PKG-INFO
....
```

I'm using python 3.8.11 and the following packages:

```
build==0.8.0
distlib==0.3.4
filelock==3.4.1
packaging==21.3
pep517==0.12.0
pip==22.0.4
platformdirs==2.4.0
pyparsing==3.0.9
setuptools==62.1.0
six==1.16.0
tomli==1.2.3
virtualenv==20.14.1
wheel==0.37.1
```

My (abbreviated) `pyproject.toml` looks like this:

```
[project]
name = "coolproject"
dependencies = [
   'pyyaml==5.3',
   'anytree==2.8.0',
   'pytest'
]
dynamic = [
   "version"
]

[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools", "wheel", "setuptools_scm[toml]>=6.2"]

[tool.setuptools_scm]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not specify the `build-backend`? Does it work if you set it to `build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"`? -- If not specified, the build front-end (_pip_) kind of defaults to invoking `setuptools.build_meta:__legacy__` instead which is probably not what you want here.

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: It should work. I do not see why it should not work. Maybe clean up things (for example: delete `dist` and `build` directories) and try again. Maybe also try without `setuptools_scm` first (make sure to set `version`).

Comment: I copied your pyproject.toml, replaced `dynamic = ["version"]` with `version = "1.0"`, did `git init && git add . && git commit -m x`, and ran `python -m build .` ... and got `coolproject-1.0` just fine.

Comment: @AKX: Doesn't work for me. Maybe an issue with the setuptools versions since PEP612 support is rather recent.

Comment: Found the problem: My "system" pip is version 19.3.1, which apparently cannot install a version of setuptools that can handle PEP612 metadata. I can't get a new pip from within the pyproject.toml by adding it to `build-system.requires`, So I need to work with `--no-isolation` for the moment.

Comment: You can install an user pip with `pip install --user pip` as a regular user...

Comment: @AKX Right! I totally forgot, because I only use venvs! Thanks, I'll try.

Comment: @AKX Finally! Thank you so much! Wanna turn your comments into an answer?

Comment: For a pure `pyproject.toml` (empty setup.cfg for editable installs), I had to set `dynamic=["version"]` and remove the version property altogether.

Comment: The build process is now extremely sensitive to where you put, and how you name your package and sub directories. basically they have to have the same exact name as you package. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74421415/1147688) on the details about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turning @AKX's comments into an answer so that other people can find it more easily.

The problem may be an outdated pip/setuptools on the system. Apparently, version 19.3.1 which I have on my system  cannot install a version of setuptools that can handle PEP621 metadata correctly.

You cannot require a new pip from within pyproject.toml using the `build-system.requires` directive.

In case you cannot update the system pip, you can always install on a per-user basis:

```
pip install --user pip
```

and you're good to go.

Answer (score 3):

On Debian/Ubuntu "UNKNOWN" packages can be created if an older system version of setuptools is installed as well.

Workaround:

```
sudo apt purge python3-setuptools
```

https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/3269

Comment: That, or upgrade the thing.