# How to replace setup.py with a pyproject.toml for a native C build dependency?

Tags: python, compilation, setup.py, pyproject.toml

I came across [this](https://pyquantnews.com/how-to-45x-python-performance-with-c/) little project for creating a C-compiled version of the *Black-Scholes* function to be used in python.

Although the example code seem to have been published in July this year, it seem that the use `setup.py` type of build has been deprecated beyond legacy builds. Any compilation fails, first complaining about missing *`MS C++ 14`* compiler (which is not true), then further investigation, seem to indicate that setup.py can no longer be used.

Q: **How can I convert the `setup.py` to a valid `pyproject.toml` file?**

```py
from setuptools import setup, Extension

ext = Extension('bs', sources=['black_scholes/bs.c'])

setup(
    name="black_scholes",
    version="0.0.1",
    description="European Options Pricing Library",
    packages=['black_scholes'],
    ext_modules=[ext]
)
```

From the somewhat ambiguous website (above), I created the following tree structure.

```bash
$ tree -L 3 ./
./
├── black_scholes
│   ├── black_scholes
│   │   ├── Makefile
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── bs.c
│   ├── pyproject.toml
│   └── setup.py
├── README.md
└── bs_test.py
```

Possibly relevant questions:

- [Is there a simple way to convert setup.py to pyproject.toml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72832052/is-there-a-simple-way-to-convert-setup-py-to-pyproject-toml)
- [Pip error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44951456/pip-error-microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required)
- [How to solve "error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required" when installing Python packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64261546/how-to-solve-error-microsoft-visual-c-14-0-or-greater-is-required-when-inst)
- ['setup.py install is deprecated' warning shows up every time I open a terminal in VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73257839/setup-py-install-is-deprecated-warning-shows-up-every-time-i-open-a-terminal-i)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After having wasted 2 days on trying to circumvent the required *Visual Studio `C++ Build tools`* requirements, the only unfortunate option that would work, was to submit to the `>7GB` download in order to get my 20 line C-function to compile and install nicely on `Py3.10`. (Follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64262038/1147688).)

#### Using an external `_custom_build.py`

Here are the files that worked:

```py
# setup.py
from setuptools import setup, Extension

ext = Extension('bs', sources=['black_scholes/bs.c'])

setup(
    name="black_scholes",
    version="0.0.1",
    description="European Options Pricing Library",
    packages=['black_scholes'],
    ext_modules=[ext]
)
```

Then for the `pyproject.toml`:

```ini
# pyproject.toml
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=61.0", "cython"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name        = "black_scholes"
description = "European Options Pricing Library"
version     = "0.0.1"
readme      = "README.md"
requires-python = ">=3.7"
authors = [
  { name="Example Author", email="author@example.com" },
]
classifiers = [
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
    "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
    "Operating System :: OS Independent",
]
keywords = ["quant", "portfolio"]

[project.urls]
"Homepage" = "https://pyquantnews.com/how-to-45x-python-performance-with-c/"

[tool.setuptools]
py-modules = ["_custom_build"]

[tool.setuptools.cmdclass]
build_py = "_custom_build.build_py"
```

This is using an external build file called `_custom_build.py`, as suggested from the SO link above.

```py
# _custom_build.py

from setuptools import Extension
from setuptools.command.build_py import build_py as _build_py

class build_py(_build_py):
    def run(self):
        self.run_command("build_ext")
        return super().run()

    def initialize_options(self):
        super().initialize_options()
        if self.distribution.ext_modules == None:
            self.distribution.ext_modules = []

        self.distribution.ext_modules.append(

            Extension(
                "bs",
                sources=["black_scholes/bs.c"],
                extra_compile_args=["-std=c17", "-lm", "-Wl", "-c", "-fPIC"],
            )
        )
```

However, it seem that the `extra_compile_args` are completely ignored...

> *It would have been great if someone could come up with an alternative solution to build using smaller compiler, like `MinGW` or so.*

The final tree should look like this:

```bash
$ tree -L 3
.
├── black_scholes
│   ├── black_scholes
│   │   ├── Makefile
│   │   └── bs.c
│   ├── .gitignore
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── _custom_build.py
│   ├── pyproject.toml
│   └── setup.py
└── bs_test.py
```

---

#### Using a `src` build with `setup.py` & `pyproject.toml`

**UPDATE: 2022-11-14**

The above procedure turned out to be very messy and also gave different results depending on how you used `pip install`. In the end I completely changed the flat folder structure to use a `src` based structure. The working project now look like this:

```bash
# tree -L 3
.
├── docs
├── examples
│   └── fbs_test.py
├── src
│   ├── black_scholes
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   └── lib
│       ├── Makefile
│       └── fbs.c
├── .gitignore
├── LICENSE.md
├── README.md
├── clean.sh
├── pyproject.toml
└── setup.py
```

and the content of the files are like this:

```py
# setup.py

from setuptools import setup, find_packages, Extension

ext = Extension(
    name                = 'black_scholes.fbs',          # 'mypackage.mymodule'
    sources             = ['src/lib/fbs.c'],            # list of source files (to compile)
    include_dirs        = ['src/lib'],                  # list of directories to search for C/C++ header files (in Unix form for portability)
    py_limited_api      = True                          # opt-in flag for the usage of Python's limited API <python:c-api/stable>.
)

setup_args = dict(
    packages        = find_packages(where="src"),       # list 
    package_dir     = {"": "src"},                      # mapping
    ext_modules     = [ext],                            # list
    scripts         = ["examples/fbs_test.py"]          # list
)

setup(**setup_args)
```

and

```py
# pyproject.toml

[build-system]
requires        = ['setuptools>=61.0']                  # 'cython'
build-backend   = 'setuptools.build_meta'   

[project]
name            = 'black_scholes'

# ...

[tool.setuptools]
package-dir = {"" = "src"}
#py-modules = ["_custom_build"]

[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
where = ["src"]
```

Here it is **very important** that the package name coincide with the `src/black_scholes` directory name. If not you will have all sorts of very weird run-time errors even after the package has compiled and installed.